# UIKit Dynamics Rotate Image

Tags: ios, uianimation, uikit-dynamics

How to achieve animation effect like lifting & dropping an object by hold at one corner. E.g When a box is lifted from the floor holding one corner, bottom layer of the box will tilt to some angle & visa versa need to applies when dropping back on floor.

[image]

I am adding anchorPoint to the Image based on the touch area & stock what to do next.

Answers/Suggestions are appreciated to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [example](http://code4app.net/ios/UIDynamicAnimator-Demo/52bb0269cb7e8472598b4771) what I am looking for. This example saved my day.

Comment: heres the url. http://www.code4app.com/ios/UIDynamicAnimator-Demo/52bb0269cb7e8472598b4771